# What graphics card is "best" in 3D on Linux?

Tags: graphics

I've been wondering about this for a while and my usual resources don't seem to really know.

The base question is; which 3D card performs the best on Linux (any distro)?

But of course, the question is really two-fold;

1) What's the best bet, performance-wise, if I insist on using strictly open-source drivers with no closed firmware or anything of the sort?

2) If the best performance can only be acquired with closed-source drivers or/or closed firmware, what's the best bet?

EDIT:

I am flabbergasted by how difficult it is to get people to even tell me anything at all about this. I don't know how to ask this in a better way so I'm leaving it closed.

Comment: This question is difficult because the hardware changes so rapidly.

Comment: If you reformulate your question to fit [this criteria](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), your question will be re-open.

Comment: Did you read the link I shared? Do you disagree with the contents? Join us on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26) and talk about it, or voice your concern on [Meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, note that such questions aren't off-topic on chat.

Comment: @Helgi See these [related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6303/250) [answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1203/250).

Comment: I've tried to ask the question in a more general way here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/how-do-i-choose-a-graphics-card-for-linux

Comment: phoronics gives great insight into this:

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Graphics%20Cards