# how to select a budget laptop for linux say fedora /ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, laptop

i need to purchase a laptop which will support linux fully.

my question:->what points should i consider laptop for linux before buying it

say should it come with os /no os/specific os
as i will  install mostly fedora or ubuntu on it.
please elaborate laptop from low budget to high budget

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which laptop is most compatible with Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1203/12779)

Comment: thanks i will check this link but also waiting for more suggestion

Comment: There are some companies which sold laptops compatible with Linux. Take a look at ThinkPenguin and SlimBook (this is a spanish site)