# does dos based laptop works fine with linux distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, laptop

[Which laptop is most compatible with Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/which-laptop-is-most-compatible-with-linux)
i checked this link but i need to know something else as below:

i need to purchase a laptop which will support linux fully when i will install say fedora and ubuntu on it

i rececntly asked to asus for their linux supporting laptop they said you can buy any dos based laptop and later you can install your own linux distro on it without any problems.

Is asus right that dos based system will work fine with linux (fedora /ubuntu)

or they are saying so for selling point of view

Comment: I think the most usual issues with linux compatibility are related to the wireless card and also the video card. I suggest you to focus on this hardware compatibilty.

Comment: There's also the touchpad (very important) and the webcam (less important) to consider. The video card is not an issue, there's only 3 choices and all work fine. Most of the time any decent laptop should work.

Comment: DOS based actually means without a graphical OS installed. It will depends greatly on what specific hardware and hardware combination they used, which isn't determined by the OS, but specific model, version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check The Hardware Compatibility list on the linux distribution's page :
For Fedora, [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HCL/Machines/Laptops) ,
For Ubuntu, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) .

You can also check on the laptop manufacturer's page what operating systems are compatible with a certain model of hardware

Comment: does ubuntu based machine does support fedora or redhat or vice versa

Comment: These things are not related to each other. I mean if a laptop is Ubuntu certified, it does not mean that it is Fedora and/or Redhat certified and vice versa. It can be certified for all, or none, or just one of these.

Comment: Fedora generally has very recent kernels, meaning that it might have hardware support that other distributions don't have yet (but will eventually). On the other hand, Fedora doesn't include proprietary binary drivers, which some distros do and which are required for some hardware.

Comment: Note that that Fedora page has not been updated in half a decade. We do not currently maintain a compatibility list.

Answer (score 1):

Dell sell laptops with Ubuntu pre-installed. For instance you can currently buy an Inspiron 15 3000 for £169. This saves any worries over wireless (often a problem) and video drivers. Note I do not work for Dell and do not use Ubuntu.